# Position and scale element on body tag with background size set to contain

Tags: javascript, css

I have this css for full page background:

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background: #c5c5c5 url(images/bkg/back4.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: contain;
```

I would like to position there a span element with a text which is supposed to stay on the same place regardless viewport size . Size of this text is supposted to adjust too in accordance to background size. I know that is possible with javascript, just cant figure out the calculations for size and position of the span.

Starting fiddle [dynamic span](https://jsfiddle.net/machumba/mracpa15/)

Comment: possible with media queries i believe

Answer (score 0):

As far as the size of the text you'd probably wanna do:

```
font-size: 16vw;
```

Comment: It scales only by changing width of a viewport, not height.

Comment: yep, that's why I never liked it. if you truly want to scale text you might need to look into css transform scale.